# Quick restoration of recent faulty edit

Tags: support, editing, specific-answer, rollbacks

I request  Quanto's post to be restored.

[Expressing $1 + \sin(x) - \cos(2x) $ as a product](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3682147/expressing-1-sinx-cos2x-as-a-product/3682301#3682301)

I had edited by error sandbox mode and pasted my own answer, an embarrassing situation.

Raised a flag 10 minutes or so and still waiting. Thanks for prompt action.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The specific problem seems to have been resolved by helpful intervention of amWhy.

For future reference, to undo an edit go to the revision history of  the post, 
this is the link in the middle of the post; it is only visible if there was an edit already. (I'll make sure that there is one for this post.)

Then, scroll to the version you want to restore, and click "rollback" in the gray banner.

To avoid a confusion, note that in the top-most gray banner there is no "rollback."

Comment: Thanks, noted this.

Comment: You're welcome, @Narasimham.  Next time don't tell me in a comment that you don't have time to read very simple instructions about what you need to do in the future to revert such a mistake.  I did the work for you.  I also gave you clear instructions, and your first reply was "I don't have time for this."  That was rude for you to say, after I solved your problem for you.

Comment: Thanks for the same again, appreciate it.  Please do not get me wrong. I wanted to use the flag facility when question was inadvertently deleted thinking it was my own ...to restore it without wasting time  reading a new method in order to give an impression to the other respondent that it was just an accident.

Comment: No problem, @Narasimham. :-)